# Angular: How to Implicitly infer types when assigning function to an output of a child component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I would like to know if it is possible to implicitly infer the type from the given example of components below :

```
@Component({
selector:'child',
template:`<button (click)="triggerChange()">Click Me</button>`
})
export class ChildComponent {
   @Output() inputchange = new EventEmitter<string>();

   triggerChange(){
      this.inputchange.emit('Hello!');
   }
}
```

while reading this output in the parent component

```
@Component({
template:`<child (inputchange)="childChanged($event)"></child>`
})
export class ParentComponent {

   childChanged(event){
      console.log(event);
   }

}
```

Currently there is no possible way to implicitly know the type of the output parameter, except if we explicitly define it ( `childChanged(event: string){ ... }`)

So the my question is is there any way to implicitly infer, or know the type of the incoming parameter (or variable) in this case?

Comment: I know this may not be the solution you're looking for but in Ivy under 'strictTemplates', the type of $event is correctly determined by the generic type of EventEmitter. Are you using Ivy strictTemplates?

Comment: In a matter of fact yes I do, and the $event type is determined correctly. But I need the type to be implicitly known inside the ts file as well.